# IIS 7 - The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis

IIS 7

1. I have a webservice that was built using Visual Studio 2013. Service.svc.
2. I've created the virtual directory.
3. I can put the above URL in a web browser and see the contents of the directory (directory browsing enabled) and I can see Service.svc
4. I click on Service.svc and it gives me the error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"
5. I change the URL in the browser to [http://localhost/Service1/Service.svc?wsdl] and the browser (doesn't matter which one) changes it to this [http://localhost/SynappsConversionService/Service.svc/?wsdl] (puts a backslash between .svc and ?wsdl.

Other notes: I have other websites on this instance of IIS that works perfectly. This same webservice works on other developers machines with the same web.config deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I have my case that I can access to service.svc and call api in localhost but when host to local IIS it was 404 error and resources not found. After I install HTTP Activation my problem was solved, hope it help you. Just go to Control Panel, then click Program, find Turn Windows features on or off under Programs and Features.  [click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC57w.png)